# SQL with Bob and John owing each other money

Tags: sql

I have got the following 3 fields in a file: person_ows person_is_owed amount

Example content:

```
Bob      John     100
John     Bob      110
```

What does a SQL look like that produces:

```
Bob    John    100    110
John   Bob     110    100
```

Sorry if this is a trivial question, but I am just trying to learn SQL and I find it really like HELL!

Comment: "*the following 3 fields in a file*" in SQL, data is stored in _tables_ not files. And the parts are called _columns_ not fields. Also: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you explain what the meaning of the file contents is? ie: is it to do with different people owing money to each other? What are the column definitions / names? What is the required output format? Why is SQL involved given you've got flat files?

Comment: I am suffering from a 'question ban' due to (I presume) poor question quality. This question has been assigned 2 down-votes which I would like to get rid off. What should I do in this particular case to fix this question? I do not dare delete it since it apparently does not help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you need is to be able to `JOIN` two rows. In this case you'll probably want an `OUTER JOIN` assuming that there isn't always a match of each owing the other. Now you just need to come up with your `JOIN` criteria, which in this case is going to be based on the names (`person_owes` and `person_is_owed`):

```
SELECT
    T1.person_owes,
    T1.person_is_owed,
    T1.amount AS owes_amount,
    COALESCE(T2.amount, 0) AS is_owed_amount
FROM
    My_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON T2.person_is_owed = T1.person_owes
```

The `COALESCE` is just to make sure that when there is no match that you get a value of 0 instead of `NULL`.

Also, this assumes that there is only going to be one of each combination of `person_owes` and `person_is_owed`. If you might have two rows showing that John owes Bill two different amounts of money then you would have to adjust the SQL above and it would be a bit more complex.

If you plan to use SQL much then you should invest the time in reading one (or preferably more) beginning books on the subject.

Comment: Great Tom. Works like a charm. Thanks. Im not planning to use SQL "much", but I realize that absolutely need to invest in a book. If you care to suggest that would be appreciated.

Comment: W3schools.com is a good reference, Udemy has some free SQL tutorials (I can't speak to the quality having never used them), otherwise just Google "sql for beginners" and you should be able to find plenty. Also, if this answer covers your question, please don't forget to mark it as the "correct" answer so that others in the future can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the combination of `(person_ows, person_is_owed)` is unique

```
select person_ows,
       person_is_owed,
       amount, 
       (select t2.amount 
        from the_table t2
        where (t2.person_ows, t2.person_is_owed) = (t1.person_is_owed, t1.person_ows)) 
from the_table t1
```

Comment: Thnx to u as well ahwnn